# SweetAlert2 Cancel button still submitting form

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a simple form with which I'm trying to use [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) to get the user to confirm their submission before submitting and processing the form.

I'm using the code below to interrupt the submission flow however the form submits regardless of whether the user presses cancel of clicks off the modal. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>

$(document).on('click', '#note_submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
         text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
        icon: "warning",
        input: 'checkbox',
        inputValue: 0,
        showCancelButton: true,
        inputPlaceholder: ' I agree with the Terms',
        confirmButtonText: 'Continue',
        inputValidator: function (result) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (result) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject('You need to agree with the Terms');
                }
            })
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        $('#notes_form').submit();
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: Are you using [SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert) or [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2)?

Answer (score 3):

Because you mentioned `inputValidator` parameter, I believe you're using [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2), not [SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert).

Another my guess is that you recently updated SweetAlert2 to the latest and didn't check the release notes with breaking changes: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v7.0.0

Starting from v7.0.0 SweetAlert2 will always fulfill the promise and in order to check whether a dialog was submitted or cancelled you need to check `result.value`:

```js
Swal.fire({
  ...
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    // A dialog has been submitted

  } else if (result.isDismissed) {
    // A dialog has been cancelled
    // For more information about handling dismissals please visit
    // https://sweetalert2.github.io/#handling-buttons
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises) uses promises to keep track of how the user interacts with the alert.

```
If the user clicks the confirm button, the promise resolves to true. 
If the alert is dismissed (by clicking outside of it), the promise resolves to null.
```

Check for `result` value before submitting

```
....    
.then(function (result) {
   if(result){
       $('#notes_form').submit();
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `then`

Replace that

```
}).then(function (result) {
        $('#notes_form').submit();
});
```

with this which will be execute what you have inside only in `OK` action

```
}, function() {
        $('#notes_form').submit();
});
```

`Cancel` button should have the default behavior and close the swal dialog without need to do anything from your side.