# form.submit(); does not run action of form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, sweetalert

I have a Laravel 5.8 project with using [sweetalert.js](https://sweetalert.js.org/).

And I have a form like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="{{ route('acceptWallet') }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <input type="checkbox" id="btn-submit" name="wallet_checked" onchange="this.form.submit();">
</form>
```

And then, here is the route `acceptWallet`:

```
Route::post('course/accept/wallet','Wallet\WalletController@acceptWallet')->name('acceptWallet');
```

And at the method `acceptWallet` of `WalletController`, I have added this:

```
public function acceptWallet(Request $request)
{
     dd($request->wallet_checked);
}
```

As you can see I have used `onchange="this.form.submit();"` to submit the form without using submit button and it works fine.

Then by using this script, I tried showing SweetAlert confirmation message box, containing **Yes** and **No** as buttons:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal(
        {
        title: "Attention!",
        text: "Are you sure you want to make this transaction",
        type: "warning",
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm) {
            form.submit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

As you can see I have used `form.submit();` if user clicks on **Yes** button in order to submit the form.

But now the problem is, the form does not submitted and just refreshes the page and not showing `dd($request->wallet_checked);` as result.

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly submit the form after showing SweetAlert popup message?

I also tried `document.forms['myForm'].submit();` instead of `form.submit();` but didn't submit the form.

Comment: first check form submittion without alert

Comment: try this document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

Comment: @NipunTharuksha It works properly without using alert

Comment: you mean without alert ?

Comment: @NipunTharuksha `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();` works correct, you can add it as answer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your  `let form = $(this).parents('form');` havent find the form correctly. So just `console.log(form)` and check is it available.

Also since there is a id for your form you can do something like below.

```
}).then((isConfirm) => {
    if (isConfirm) {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
       //Or $('#myForm').submit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Or jest make your variable with jquery via id

```
let form =  $('#myForm')
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more problem, if I press on **No** button, it still calls the Action!!

Comment: you mean form get submitted ?

Comment: Yes, when the dialog box appears on screen, if I press on **No** button, it should just stays at the same page but still redirects to `acceptWallet` route and call the Controller.

Comment: this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822354/sweetalert2-cancel-button-still-submitting-form